# Facing mvn problems

Tags: maven, visual-studio-code

When i´ve try executing any mvn command, console shows this error:

```
Error: -classpath requires class path specification
```

How can I solve this error?

I´m using apache-maven-3.8.3 version on Windows 10 OS.
My `M2_HOME` variable is in `C:\apache-maven-3.8.3\`, and `JAVA_HOME` is in `C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-17.0.1.12-hotspot\`.

Comment: Have you seen [Maven Error: "Error: -classpath requires class path specification"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69418610/1744774) already?

Comment: Remove `M2_HOME` only put the location of your bin folder (of the apache maven distro) into your `PATH`...

Comment: Thanks a lot, guys. I was a wrong maven archive (source code, instead bin code).

Answer (score 1):

With a help of `Gerold Broser` comment, there is the solution: [Maven Error: "Error: -classpath requires class path specification"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69418610/maven-error-error-classpath-requires-class-path-specification)

I downloaded a wrong maven archive: source code, instead of bin code.